# NLS_SORT is not used in partial select

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have set the `nls_sort` parameter to `BINARY_AI` to perform sort case insensitive. I set it in the system and the session:

```
alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_AI';
alter system set nls_sort='BINARY_AI' scope=spfile;
```

The sort is correct with this query:

```
SELECT s."Id", s."Label" FROM "Software" s ORDER BY s."Label"

    Id   |  Label
_______________________
10218    | Able2Extract
10217    | AVS Video Recorder
```

If i execute a partial select with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Label" ASC) AS MYROW, subSelect.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT s."Id", s."Label" FROM "Software" s
    ) subSelect
) WHERE MYROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

The sort is not case insensitive :

```
    Id   |  Label
_______________________
10217    | AVS Video Recorder
10218    | Able2Extract
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a sort order specified in the second query because you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, so the results as returned in an indeterminate order.

Your `MYROW` value is being assigned based on the NLS sort order, but you then only use that to filter, not to sort the result set. You can either use that again:

```
SELECT "Id", "Label" FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Label" ASC) AS MYROW, subSelect.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT s."Id", s."Label" FROM "Software" s
    ) subSelect
) WHERE MYROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY MYROW;
```

Or order by label:

```
SELECT "Id", "Label" FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Label" ASC) AS MYROW, subSelect.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT s."Id", s."Label" FROM "Software" s
    ) subSelect
) WHERE MYROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY "Label";
```

You also don't need two levels of subquery when you use `ROW_NUMBER`, as you would with `ROWNUM`; you can simplify that a bit to:

```
SELECT "Id", "Label" FROM (
    SELECT s."Id", s."Label",
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s."Label" ASC) AS MYROW
    FROM "Software" s
) WHERE MYROW BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY "Label";
```

The inner query returns the expect values for `MYROW` (compare on SQL Fiddle, [for 'binary'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8db657/2) and [for 'binary_ai'](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8db657/1)). But that is using 11.2.0.2, and it also works for me in 11.2.0.3. I don't have a 12c instance to test on at the moment, but someone else may be able to verify the behaviour there.

If you're seeing the wrong value for `MYROW` in 12.1.0.1, you *might* be hitting bug 18353141 or 16934803, both of which look in the right area, and are mentioned in the 12.1.0.2 patch set release notes. Check [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1683802.1) for details.

Comment: No, it's not that i want because the sort is applied after the partial select. So if the value "AVS Video Recorder" has a row number to 100 and "Able2Extract" has a row number to 101 then the sort is case insensitive but it is applied too late and the value "Able2Extract" will not be in the result when the value "AVS Video Recorder" will be in the result. If i add a sort in the subselect, there is no effect....  NLS_SORT would be applied in the ORDER BY of the OVER clause but it's not the case. Is it a bug?

Comment: @Troopers - I'm not seeing that. With just your two values, the inner select gives "Able2Extract" a MYROW value of 1, and "AVS Video Recorder" a value of 2, which is what you want I think. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8db657/1). (And the reverse order [with BINARY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8db657/2)).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It's work with a Oracle 11g database but i am unable to work it on a Oracle 12c database. Could you confirm this?

Comment: Mmm, interesting; sorry though I don't have access to 12c at the moment. Might be worth editing the question to say exactly which version/patch level you're seeing this behaviour in, in case it's a bug that's already been fixed.

Comment: If you're on 12.1.0.1, this *might* be bug 18353141 or 16934803, both of which look in the right area, and are mentioned in the 12.1.0.2 patch set release notes. You can check My Oracle Support for more details, and/or raise a service request to confirm the issue. If you're already on 12.1.0.2 then you might need to raise a service request anyway.

Comment: Ok, I was with Oracle 12.1.0.1, I have installed Oracle 12.1.0.2 and now the sort is case insensitive with the partial select. Thank you very much!